# iOS firebase installation registration failed

Tags: ios, firebase

I got the error "firebase installation registration failed" when I started the application. I integrated it step by step according to the documents. Now I can't find the cause of the error. Can you help me? thank you!

Here is the log:
Firebase Installation registration failed for app with name: __FIRAPP_DEFAULT, error:
The server responded with an error:

- URL: https://firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com/v1/projects/tleva-284009/installations/
- HTTP status code: 403
- Response body: {
  "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Requests to this API firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com method google.firebase.installations.v1.FirebaseInstallationsService.CreateInstallation are blocked.",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
  "details": [
  {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
  "reason": "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED",
  "domain": "googleapis.com",
  "metadata": {
  "consumer": "projects/283202179632",
  "service": "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com"
  }
  }
  ]
  }
  }

Comment: Can you provide us brief information on what steps you used? Was this a podfile? Did you install cocoapods? Is it up-to-date? Did you include the GoogleService-Info.plist file in your project? Does the app include any code? Which Firebase product are you using? We really need some further details if you want assistance.

Comment: OK,Thanks! I Integrate the latest Cloud Messaging: pod 'firebase / messaging', and operate step by step according to the official documents. The project has the correct Google service-info.plist file and the necessary initialization code.

Comment: I just stepped through the official documents and created a project that compiled and worked correctly with no error. That means that you missed a step somewhere. When someone asks for more information, please provide it - we need to know what version of cocoapods is installed `pod --version`, what version of Firebase is installed and please include your podfile in the question. Also, log into the Firebase Console->Project Overview->Settings->General and re-download and install the GoogleService-Info.plist file into your project.

Comment: Seeing the same issue. Updating Firebase pods from 8.1.1. to 8.2.0 didn't change anything. (Cocoapods version 1.10.1). Also, re-added plists (some had changed API key somehow?) didn't make the error go away. The same code base also builds an app for another brand. Nearly identical with regards to Firebase and doesn't show this error.

Comment: Pretty bold btw to state "That means that you missed a step somewhere." It could very well also be a configuration issue at Firebase. Of course sharing which version of the code is used is essential, but not everything is an "user" error.

Comment: Hi @JohanKool, did you resolve this issue? if yes can you please share the details.

Answer (score 0):

If API restriction enables then add 'Firebase Installations' Fixed this error  "API_KEY_SERVICE_BLOCKED"

[image]